# "don't know of" vs. "haven't known of"

Tags: tense

Two friends are talking about movies.

> A: "LEFT BEHIND is a really bad movie. I never watched in its entirety."

> B: "I **don't even know** of that movie!"

or should B say this way

> B: "I **haven't even known** of that movie!"

Which one is correct for this particular situation?

Comment: _Haven't knew_ is ungrammatical - it's _haven't known_ - but this is not idiomatic. What Bob would say is "I haven't even heard of that movie!"

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you. I corrected it. In what kind of situation, "haven't known" is more idiomatic?

Comment: "Mary is my new friend. I haven't known her very long, but I like her very much."